# Creating a Compute Engine instance for managing BigQuery in Google Cloud

Tags: google-bigquery, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I need a VM to load data into an existing BigQuery table.

I create a new Compute Engine with:

1. The scope having access to all Cloud APIs
2. Default service account (auto-generated name `...-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`)
3. This service account having "Editor" permissions in the project

This VM allows me to read BQ with `bq ls`, but when I try editing with `bq rm <dataset>`, it says

```
...-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have permission to delete dataset
```

What is wrong? Is it possible to give the full access to BQ to the instance, like the one Cloud Shell has?

Or the VM should authenticate as described here: [How to auth into BigQuery on Google Compute Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031492/how-to-auth-into-bigquery-on-google-compute-engine)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a dataset, you need "Owner" permissions on the dataset or the containing project.

More info about access control can be found here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/access-control

Comment: Thanks! I changed the ownership. Now it says `BigQuery error in rm operation: Dataset is still in use` (to all "Owner" accounts). How can I debug  this?

Comment: Solved this problem with `bq rm -r -f  <dataset>`.